# Подписи полигонов - падение производительности (альтернативы?)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Попробовал данный пример (но только текстовые и пока без обработчика событий)
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/polylabeler/

заметил сильную просадку производительности на 250 полигонов.
Все тормозит как при отрисовки, но что еще хуже — при перемещении по карте.

Тормозит именно после добавления кода отвечающего за подписи, без него все работает шустро.

```
 // Запускаем модуль подписей.
        var polylabel = new ymaps.polylabel.create(map, objectManager);
```

Отображаю только номер полигона (3х значное число)
С этим можно как-то бороться? или есть какие-то альтернативные решения проблемы или идеи?

Попробовал еще этот метод (svg в fillImageHref) https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/kak-dobavit-podpis-k-poligonu
он работает быстро, как и без подписей, но по понятным причинам — искажает (а иногда обрезает) текст. т.к. полигоны разной формы и размеров. Да и в целом такое решение подходит плохо (при большом масштабе подписи будут не читаемы — хотя готов даже этим пожертвовать, если в остальном будет отображаться нормально).

Так же появилась идея попробовать нечто подобное (добавить метки в центр полигонов): https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/47313
Но пока еще не пробовал (т.к. с метками основательно не работал и нет полной уверенности в удовлетворительном результате, и пока есть другие задачи)